# Убираем дублирование с помощью тегов

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, теги, django-template

у меня появился вопрос: есть код(вьюха), я создал теги для него, как при помощи тегов убрать дублирование?

Теги:

```
from django import template

from recipes.models import Follow, Recipe

register = template.Library()


@register.filter(name='extend_context')
def extend_context(context, user):
    context['purchase_list'] = Recipe.objects.filter(purchase_by=user)
    context['favorites'] = Recipe.objects.filter(favorite_by=user)
    return context


@register.filter(name='add_subscription_status')
def add_subscription_status(context, user, author):
    context['is_subscribed'] = Follow.objects.filter(
        user=user, author=author
    ).exists()
    return context
```

Код вьюхи:

```
@require_GET
def recipe_detail(request, recipe_id):
    recipe = get_object_or_404(Recipe, id=recipe_id)
    context = {
        'recipe': recipe,
    }
    user = request.user
    if user.is_authenticated:
        add_subscription_status(context, user, recipe.author) - дублирование
        extend_context(context, user) - дублирование
    return render(request, 'recipes/recipe_detail.html', context)
```

---

```
@require_GET
def profile(request, user_id):
    author = get_object_or_404(User, id=user_id)
    tags = request.GET.getlist('tag')
    recipe_list = tag_filter(Recipe, tags)
    paginator = Paginator(recipe_list.filter(author=author), PAGINATE_BY)
    page_number = request.GET.get('page')
    page = paginator.get_page(page_number)
    context = {
        'tags': Tag.objects.all(),
        'author': author,
        'page': page,
        'paginator': paginator
    }
    user = request.user
    if user.is_authenticated:
        add_subscription_status(context, user, author) - дублирование
        extend_context(context, user) - дублирование
    return render(request, 'recipes/profile.html', context)
```

Comment: непонятно, о каком дублировании речь.

Comment: поправил, теперь должно быть понятнее :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант создайте функцию `create_context`:

```
def create_context(request, **kwargs):
   user = request.user
   if user.is_authenticated:
       add_subsription(kwargs, user, author)
       extend_context(kwargs, user)
   return kwargs


@require_GET
def recipe_detail(request, recipe_id):
    recipe = get_object_or_404(Recipe, id=recipe_id)
    context = create_context(request, recipe=recipe)
    return render(request, 'recipes/recipe_detail.html', context)

@require_GET
def profile(request, user_id):
    author = get_object_or_404(User, id=user_id)
    tags = request.GET.getlist('tag')
    recipe_list = tag_filter(Recipe, tags)
    paginator = Paginator(recipe_list.filter(author=author), PAGINATE_BY)
    page_number = request.GET.get('page')
    page = paginator.get_page(page_number)
    context = create_context(
        request,
        tags=Tag.objects.all(),
        author=author,
        page=page,
        paginator=paginator
    )
    return render(request, 'recipes/profile.html', context)
```

И теги здесь ни при чем. Это могут (и должны, если вы их не используете в шаблонах) быть обыкновенные функции.